# automate download of file using python selenium or request modules

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, python-requests

I am trying to download file from URL https://www.mca.gov.in/content/mca/global/en/data-and-reports/company-llp-info/incorporated-closed-month.html

[image]

#https://www.mca.gov.in/bin/dms/getdocument?mds=kSK4UVGwah4CaBAtANCECQ%253D%253D&type=download

I tried following code

```
import requests

def download_file(url, output_file_path):
    try:
        response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        response.raise_for_status()

        with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
            for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=8192):
                output_file.write(chunk)

        print(f"File downloaded successfully to '{output_file_path}'.")

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(f"Error downloading the file: {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    file_url = "https://www.mca.gov.in/bin/dms/getdocument?mds=kSK4UVGwah4CaBAtANCECQ%253D%253D&type=download"
    output_file_path = "path/to/your/file.csv"

    download_file(file_url, output_file_path)
```

if we paste download link in browser manually it will  download file. link(https://www.mca.gov.in/bin/dms/getdocument?mds=kSK4UVGwah4CaBAtANCECQ%253D%253D&type=download)

kindly suggest Python code to automate this download task.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code works fine. Except for the fact that you are trying to save an xlsx file to csv. Save it to XLSX and it works fine.

My simple example is below, but in reality, just change your output file to .xlsx

```
import requests

url = "https://www.mca.gov.in/bin/dms/getdocument?mds=kSK4UVGwah4CaBAtANCECQ%253D%253D&type=download"

payload = {}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

with open('test.xlsx', 'wb') as output_file:
    output_file.write(response.content)
```